# Do all time series necessarily have a level?

Tags: time-series, modeling, terminology

Most articles on time series modeling mention level, seasonality, and trend as components of a time series. A time series need not have seasonality or trend. In one of the courses that I've taken up we were taught that level is a necessary component of a time series. Is this true? If yes, then what exactly would be the level for a time series that only linearly increases with time? Would it simply be a rolling mean?

Comment: Hi: if the series is increasing linearly with time, then it's trend stationary so there is no constant mean as it stands. But you could estimate $\beta$ ( the time coefficient ) and then take it out and see if there's still a mean. It's possible that the mean is zero. Also, check out "trend-stationary" processes for more details.

Comment: @mlofton Thanks for your response. I do understand how trend-stationarity works. If the process was stationary, it makes sense to think of the series as having a level which here would simply be the mean at which the series tends to converge. For a process which is purely linear in time, does it make sense to say that it has a level component? Because then the level depends on the time interval you choose and will itself be a linear function of time. Why is it said that every time series has a level component instead of just talking about the mean of the series for a chosen time interval?

Comment: Hi: I think the reason that they always say that a series has a mean even in the case of trend is because, if you take the trend out, there can still be some mean ( it could be zero of course but that's still a mean ). That mean  is independent of the time interval chosen. So, you can estimate $\beta$ in the $\beta \times time $ term in the original series, then take the original series and remove that trend component from it and see what the mean is. That mean will not be dependent on the interval chosen.